# BlackBerry 10 / WebWorks 2 send email automatically

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

I'm writing an app to prepare an email message with data provided by the user in a form.  Upon the user clicking "finish" in the form, the email message gets prepared on the email card, but the user still has to click Send.

I used this method to prepare the message: `blackberry.invoke.card.invokeEmailComposer`.  How do I get the message to send immediately after the message is prepared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That behavior is currently not available. As you describe, the invokeEmailComposer() method opens a new screen (named a 'Card') where the user can confirm/modify/cancel/submit an email.

One of the benefits of the emailComposer card is that you give the user the ability to select which email account they wish to send it from (e.g. if they have both a personal and work account on the device).